# How to select multiple folders and files in Javafx2?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I am working on `javafx 2.` but there is no feature of multiple folders and files available on the `filechooser`.

There is the `Directory chooser` but it selects only one folder. How can i solve this problem. Please give me any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried the `showOpenMultipleDialog` method?

Comment: Thanks assylias. This method works on only files. But i want also multiple folders.

Comment: It is documented in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html). But the DirectoryChooser does not seem to have the same option...

Comment: assylias.. i know this. But this is not solution of my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use JFileChooer of Swing component. But then its give error like Headless something. So   remove this error by following steps.

1) Initialised all component of swing before javafx.
2) use System.setProperty and set Headless false .

Then jfilechooser works. Thanks to all.

Comment: Any idea how to pop the dialog to the front in a JavaFX application? I have a problem where my JavaFX scene is hiding the JFileChooser dialog when it pops under.

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX supports single and multiple file dialogs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html

and single directory dialog:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html

There was a special RFE for this : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8101526.

There is a special RFE for multiple directories chosign, you can wait, until it will be fixed : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091403, also, you can vote it up, for it to be fixed with higher priority

Comment: thanks Alexander. But i want some suggestion or solutions for this. I have urgent requirement of this.

Comment: Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: One of ways to get the multi-folder selector now - is to implement it by your self, as far as I understand, or use possibility of jfx to interoperate with other technologies - swing, or swt (may be they have). Because folder chosers - is a low level mechanism, and for implementation some fixes in low level are needed, and you are not able to do them

Comment: Also, I saw a sample of TreeView, when treeView is used as file-system explorer. you can use it, if switch multiple selection in treeView on.

Comment: For instance from here http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-simple-file-browser