# JFilechooser hangs on calling .showOpenDialog

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser from the swing framework because DirectoryChooser from JavaFX does not allow multiple selections.

On the following line my application hangs without any information.

```
if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
```

I have it working in a different project so I traced my steps, the only difference seemed to be where I set my `JavaFX` stage width and height so i set this back to default in `Main`:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275)); // JFilechooser dialog works properly
```

Now the JFileChooser dialog works properly. Previously this line was:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 720)); // JFilechooser dialog hangs
```

The thing is, I really need a bigger Scene window otherwise my GUI does not fit. Any idea what could cause this issue to happen with different `JAVAFX` scene sizes?

-**update**-
The actual issue is that the dialog is shown behind my main scene (which becomes unresponsive) and thus it looks like it is hanging. I have tried to request and grab focus but it does not pop in front.

Comment: hm, can you clarify pls, why are you using JFileChooser from swing in javaFX, instead of javaFX component?

Comment: @AlexG. I need to select multiple folders, DirectoryChooser from javaFX does not have that functionality AFAIK.

Comment: @Pagbo Yes, you are right. Anyway, I discovered that the window actually pops under my JavaFX scene and I cannot get it to front since I have to pass null instead of a proper parent component from Swing.

Comment: Do you configure and call your `JFileChooser` in the Event Dispath Thread or in the JavaFX one ? What is your `Stage` modality and `StageStyle` ? Did you remove the head of the JFileChooser (as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621721/4629012), I did not try it on my own so I don't know the validity of this answer) ?

Comment: @Pagbo I'm calling JFileChooser in the controller of a single window app atm. So I guess in the JavaFX thread. I'm just initializing it there and open the dialog on a button click. I tried `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");` in `static void main(...)` without success.

Comment: I made some tries. The GUI do not hang when the `JFileChooser` is initialized in the EDT (what was expected). But if you click elswhere (on a JavaFX component), the JFileChooser pass behind the main window (also as expected because instantiated with null `parameter`). I mean, this is the normal behaviour, but not the one expected. 
I also tried with `SwingNode` from JavaFX, it could work even if it could be hard to manage all the events on each side (Swing side and JavaFX one).
FInally I think it could be easier and quicker to create your own DirectoryChooser in JavaFX.